# oracle database query for getting monthly salary and total salary

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where monthly salary of employees are stored.

```
create table myemp
( 
 empno number ,
 month number,
 year number,
 salary number
);
```

Now i need a query to get results like below

```
empno|month|Year|salary
0001    2   2016        10000
0001    3   2016    11000
0001    4   2016    12000
0001    --  ----    (10000+11000+12000)
0002    2   2016    15000
0002    3   2016    16000
0002    4   2016    15000
0002    --  ----(15000+16000+15000)
```

Comment: are want to get total rows and grand total rows in oracle select statement output ?

Comment: yes @sanjay radadiya

Comment: empno is primary key, whence empno 0001 four times in result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set total and subtotal using [Rollup](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets) function of oracle like given below

```
select empno,month,year,sum(salary) from myemp
GROUP BY year,ROLLUP (empno,month)
```

here empno and month are in rollup function that gives total and subtotal of 
empno and month group.

i hope this will help.

Comment: `GROUP BY empno, ROLLUP((year,month))`. Double brackets for suppress year subtotal.

Comment: yes @Mike thanks for your help i am aware of this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    (
        SELECT empno, month, year, salary
        FROM myemp
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT empno, NULL AS month, NULL AS year, sum(salary)
        FROM myemp
        GROUP BY empno
    )
) AS foo
ORDER BY empno, year IS NULL, year, month
```

Answer (score 0):

would look like this 
select lastname , dept_no, salary,
      sum(salary) over (partition by dept_no order by lastname) dept_total
from myemp
order by salary, lastname;

Comment: Instead of adding a separate answer, simply edit your original answer and delete this one.  Or delete the other one and keep this one.  you pick.